# Disable keybord on mobile borwsers when useing React DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-datepicker

I am using react date-picker and I have a problem on mobile view.
The virtual keyboard hides part of my date picker.
Any advise?

```
<DatePicker
      className={css.datePicker}
      todayButton={'Today'}
      selected={date}
      onChange={this.changeHandler}
      onBlur={this.handleBlur}
      name={this.props.name}
      minDate={this.store.state.searchParameters.Arrival}
      disabledKeyboardNavigation
      withPortal={isMobileView}
      onChangeRaw={e => e.preventDefault()}
      onFocus={e => e.preventDefault()}
      onKeyDown={e => e.preventDefault()}/>
```

thnx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide native keyboard on mobile when using react-date-picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805053/hide-native-keyboard-on-mobile-when-using-react-date-picker)

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805053/hide-native-keyboard-on-mobile-when-using-react-date-picker?rq=1) worked for me! I put it in the wrapper component as in componenetDidMount().

Answer (score 1):

```
handleDateChangeRaw = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}

...

render() {
  ...
  <DatePicker onChangeRaw={this.handleDateChangeRaw} ... />
  ...
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/942#issuecomment-424939438) is the source