# How to prevent keyboard to pop up when tapped on InputField in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I have the following code:

```
<TextField
            InputProps={{
                readOnly: true
            }}
            value={5000}
            multiline={false}
            autoFocus
        />
```

I want the keyboard to not popup when the user taps on the InputField. The cursor should blink as it is. The `readOnly` prop only makes it uneditable but the keyboard still pops up in mobile browsers.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805053/hide-native-keyboard-on-mobile-when-using-react-date-picker

Comment: <TextField disabled={true} .... try this

Comment: @9841pratik disabled={true} also removes the blinking cursor.